# Numbered equations in footnotes

Tags: footnotes

Is it wrong, from a typographical point of view, to have numbered equations in footnotes? Is there a good practice about it?

E.g., when I edit manuscripts, I often encounter cases like this:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{equation}
  x+y=z
\end{equation}
\blindtext\footnote{\begin{equation}
  x+y=z
\end{equation}}
\begin{equation}
  x+y=z
\end{equation}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my opion numbers equations never belongs in the footnotes. As you already show, the numbering is then inconsistent on the page. I have never seen such a thing being used in the wild.

Comment: I think that footnotes convey auxiliary information with respect to the main text. If an equation is numbered the implication is that at some point in the document it will be referred to and hence is not "auxiliary". Don't put numbered equations in footnotes (nor in end notes).